# Shared account unable to access the objects shared with them in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am using the below queries to create a share and add objects to it:

```
CREATE SHARE IF NOT EXISTS my_db_my_schema_my_table;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE my_db TO SHARE my_db_my_schema_my_table;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_db.my_schema TO SHARE my_db_my_schema_my_table;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE my_db.my_schema.my_table TO SHARE my_db_my_schema_my_table;
```

Now, I am using the below query to add the accounts:

```
ALTER SHARE my_db_my_schema_my_table ADD ACCOUNTS=AB60942;
```

This works fine. No errors. Also, I can see in the share details that this account name was added under `Full Accounts`.

Below are my current role permissions:
[image]

However, I am not able to see anything under the other account. What exactly am I missing here?

**P.S**: I am trying to refrain myself from using `accountadmin` role.

Comment: The alter share command should pass the account parameter along with the Orgname as <orgname.acccount> : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-share.html#examples

Comment: It works both ways. I tried and can see the results. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the ACCOUNTADMIN role (or a role granted the IMPORT SHARES global privilege) to perform these tasks:

Do you see your shares in the available /inbound shares on the consumer account?

```
show shares;
```

Have you created a database from the share on the consumer account?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-consumers.html#creating-a-database-from-a-share

Are your consumer and the main account in the same region? If they are in different regions, follow this document: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/secure-data-sharing-across-regions-plaforms.html

Comment: Ohh! I just realized that both provider and consumer accounts are in a different regions. One is in `eu-west-1` and other is in `eu-central-1`. How can I rectify this thing?

Comment: For the provider account, I followed this https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-privileges-shares.html#enabling-non-accountadmin-roles-to-perform-data-sharing-tasks and it worked fine. I can see this in the `private sharing > shared by my account` and I can see the account name with whom I shared the data. No errors

Comment: If they are in different regions, follow this one: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/secure-data-sharing-across-regions-plaforms.html